# Flutter:How to inherit the subclass of StatefulWidget to modify the use of a certain attribute？

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, if I want to implement a component with the same function as CachedNetworkImage, but change one of the optional parameters to a mandatory parameter or modify a parameter name, how should I write the code?
I tried to write the following code, but no other attributes such as color can be used.

I think inheriting Text is the same problem.

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UU extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        NetWorkImage(
          'url',
        ),
        CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: 'asdad',
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        MyText(
          'aa',
          TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NetWorkImage extends CachedNetworkImage {
  @override
  NetWorkImage(String url) : super(imageUrl: url);
}

class MyText extends Text {
  MyText(String data, TextStyle style) : super(data, style: style);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in the overridden constructor you've added 'url' as the only argument, you will not be able to pass other arguments of the base class.

Use '**required**' keyword to make a parameter mandatory

To get all parameter as part of your extended function, I think you have to copy past all the parameter of the base constructor and rename it based on your needs and call the super function with the relevant parameter names.
for eg you can have a constructor like this,

```
NetworkImage({required String myImageURL, /*all custom arguments here*/}):super(imageUrl: myImageURL);
```

I'd suggest not to extend a class just for renaming or marking the parameter as required, unless there is a real need for it.

Please also refer: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors

Comment: thanks. Does this mean if I want to extend the class, I must rewrite all the parameters?

Comment: Since the constructors are not inherited in Dart, the inherited class has to call the super constructor from it's constructor with the necessary params to its base class. If you want to expose only certain params as part of your new class, then you can just add it as part of your inherited class's constructor and skip the other params if others are not needed. or you can pass default values to base class's constructor from your new class

Answer (score 0):

You should add the color attribute (not sure about the syntax) :

```
class NetWorkImage extends CachedNetworkImage {
  Color color;
  NetWorkImage(String url, this.color) : super(imageUrl: url);

  // Do domething with color attribute
}
```